# select distinct value from 1 column only with multiple column?

Tags: sql

```
Model Name  seq number
ABC         1
ABC         2
ABC         3
PQR         4
PQR         5
PQR         6
XYZ         7
XYZ         8
XYZ         9
```

so I only want distinct from Model Name field but not distinct from Seq number  field.

Comment: What are your desired results?  And which database are you using?

Comment: using ms sql. desire result should have at least 1 model name and any 1 seq number for each model name so only 3 result. ABC 1 PQR 4 and XYZ 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment and question and assuming you are using tSQL

this should do it:

```
 SELECT [Model Name],
        MIN([seq number]) AS [seq number] 
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY [Model Name]
```

Comment: @BinitPatel your welcome, if it indeed worked for you then please then accept the answer.